# Swift MapKit Annotations

Tags: swift, ios8, mapkit

I am attemping to add annotations to my app I am having trouble appending to AnyObject. The two entries (Annotation 1 Detail and 2) seem to append to the object except the second annotation overrides the first entry and I end up with 2 objects with the same detail from annotation 2.

```
    var locations = [AnyObject]()
    var myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    // Annotation 1 Detail
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-38.219836, 146.246249)
    myAnnotation.title = "Annotation Pin 1"
    myAnnotation.subtitle = "Pin 1"
    locations.append(myAnnotation)

    // Annotation 2 Detail
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.219836, 146.246249)
    myAnnotation.title = "Annotation Pin 2"
    myAnnotation.subtitle = "Pin 2"
    locations.append(myAnnotation)
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
// ...
locations.append(myAnnotation)
// ...
locations.append(myAnnotation)
```

In the first line, you make one MKPointAnnotation object. An MKPointAnnotation is a class instance - a reference type. `myAnnotation` is therefore *the same object* each time. You are just appending two references to it into your array. They are not magically copied! They are two references to *one and the same thing*.

So your changes to `myAnnotation` *after* appending the reference for the first time *change* what the first reference is pointing to, because it is still pointing to the same object. Simpler example:

```
class Dog {
    var name : String = ""
}

var arr : [Dog] = []

var d = Dog()
d.name = "Rover"
arr.append(d)
d.name = "Fido"
arr.append(d) // now arr is [{name "Fido"}, {name "Fido"}]
```

Easy solution: make *two* MKPointAnnotation objects! Ooooh, what a concept!!! Configure them separately, add them to the array separately. Problem solved.

```
class Dog {
    var name : String = ""
}

var arr : [Dog] = []

var d = Dog()
d.name = "Rover"
arr.append(d)
d = Dog() // oooh! what a concept! _another_ Dog!!!!
d.name = "Fido"
arr.append(d) // now arr is [{name "Rover"}, {name "Fido"}]
```

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_value_types_and_reference_types

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was stuck and your example makes sense. Cheers.